# Check if iFrame starts to render or onload by Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

I know I cannot check the content in an iframe that contains 3rd party web page.

All I want is simple, when I create an iframe, I want to get a callback when the page triger onload, or starts to render, or domready, or other events which I can know the URL is working (is not a dead link)

Anyidea which events should I hook to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("the_frame");
iframe.onload = function () {
    alert("hey man!");
}
```

Comment: I am currently use this method. Not reliable, sometime work, sometime now. And no idea why

Comment: Maybe the page loads before you've attached the `onload` event?

Comment: @Frits_van_Campen, I only create an empty `iframe` with `onload`, then change src, seems better, thanks.